# Xamarin Proguard Error 1

Tags: android, xamarin, size, apk, proguard

I wanted to use proguard with xamarin to shrink my app, but i constantly have this error when i enable proguard:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       "java.exe" exited with code 1 .Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   line 1922

The error comes from the file Xamarin.Android.Common.targets, the error locates in "

```
<Proguard
Condition="'$(AndroidEnableProguard)' == 'True' and 
'$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)' != ''"
ProguardJarPath="$(ProguardJarPath)"
AndroidSdkDirectory="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)"
JavaToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
ProguardToolPath="$(ProguardToolPath)"
ToolExe="$(ProguardToolExe)"
UseProguard="$(UseProguard)"
JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)"
ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg"
ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration="$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)"
ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg"
ProguardConfigurationFiles="$(ProguardConfigFiles)"
JavaLibrariesToEmbed="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompile);@(_InstantRunJavaReference)"
ExternalJavaLibraries="@(AndroidExternalJavaLibrary)"
DoNotPackageJavaLibraries="@(_ResolvedDoNotPackageAttributes)"
ProguardJarInput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_input__.jar"
ProguardJarOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"
EnableLogging="$(ProguardEnableLogging)"
DumpOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\dump.txt"
PrintSeedsOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\seeds.txt"
PrintUsageOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\usage.txt"
PrintMappingOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\mapping.txt"
 />
```

I search on the website and i did all the possible solution:
- i update proguard in android-sdk/tools
- i use java newest version
- i changed proguard-xamarin.cfg file
- uncheck Proguard, clean solution, build solution, then recheck proguard, and build solution.
- installing facebook proguard in nugget manager

But nothing works.

Is there an ultime solution to use it?

Thanks.

Regards, Sam.

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build log.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  "java.exe" exited with code 1. Random Number C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1922

Comment: Have you tried to set your Linking to "None" instead of "SDK Assemblies Only"?

Comment: when i set to none, it works, but i wanted to use SDK Assemblies and Proguard, to shrink my apk.

Comment: @SamMcFly https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: >  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. (TaskId:247)
1>   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Unknown Source) (TaskId:247)
1>   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(Unknown Source) (TaskId:247)
1>   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(Unknown Source) (TaskId:247)
1>   at proguard.ProGuard.main(Unknown Source) (TaskId:247)
1>  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 (TaskId:247)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1922,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
1>Done executing task "Proguard" -- FAILED. (TaskId:247)